# jpa and java bean foreignkey validation

Tags: java, json, jpa, jax-rs, javabeans

I have following User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group group;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The Resourse gets json in format `{name: "abc", group: 1}`

I can validate whether user is null or not using `@NotNull`. But i also want to validate whether the group id is present in database.

What will be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write some code in the getter of group.
The getter-method must lookup, if the group-id exists.
i dont know exactly, but i'm eager to help.I think, you must declare it as a many-to-one-relation.

Here's a code-expl.

Example 1: One-to-Many association using generics

In `Customer` class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
public Set getOrders() { return orders; }
```

In `Order` class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

Example 2: One-to-Many association without using generics

In `Customer` class:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=com.acme.Order.class, cascade=ALL,
        mappedBy="customer")
public Set getOrders() { return orders; }
```

In `Order` class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```